# Unable to send email from rcp eclipse application

Tags: email, eclipse-rcp

i have a strange problem. We have wrote a simple eclipse plugin to send email, we use javax.mail.

When we start the plugin from Eclipse it works and sends email, when we export the plugin and start it from eclipse.exe we receive this error

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection error (java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect))
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
    at pluginmailapache.Application4.start(Application4.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection error (java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect)
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:408)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:242)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:85)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:70)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:94)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:249)
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.getConnectedSocket(SMTPTransport.java:1096)
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.getConnection(SMTPTransport.java:856)
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:385)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the application with disabled firewall.

You probably save the email settings somewhere.Check if they are saved correctly and if they are used properly in the code.

Have you tried the .exe on the same pc or on a different one ?

Comment: Finally i found the problem... antivirus!